# what does the 'm' unit in munin mean?

Tags: munin

I'm using munin as a tool for monitoring my servers. On some of the graphs, the units are marked with a '`m`'. For instance, my apache accesses graph is labeled 100m, 200m, 300m, along the y-axis. What does the '`m`' mean? I understand '`M`' (caps) is mega as in megabytes, the '`k`' is kilo, the '`G`' is giga, but what about '`m`'?  At first I thought it was million, but there's no way apache is serving 100 million accesses even per decade.

Comment: See also [this question on the same topic, with a sample graph and comments that line up with comments here](http://serverfault.com/questions/326281/how-to-read-the-scale-of-the-munin-monitoring-system-tomcat-accesses-by-day-gra). Also I second [Edward Ross's comments](http://serverfault.com/questions/123761/what-does-the-m-unit-in-munin-mean#comment318794_123766) about changing time units to deal with this very unclear way of handling fractional data values.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The 'm' stands for [milli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milli), meaning 10^(-3) or 1/1000th of the unit.

Comment: The confusing thing with munin here appears to be using the "m" on accesses per second axis, to indicate a fractional access, which is a slightly strange concept.  It might be more intuitive for munin to switch the time period, to say accesses per minute or accesses per hour.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly you are graphing there but it could be the average processing time per request. So it would be milliseconds.